# Import and Export multi language theme issue

Tags: sxa, multilingual

I have configured multi-language in my SXA environment. The default language is English (en) when I created my site. I want to support LTR in English language and RTL in other language.

When I try to export the theme in English language and made my changes I found that the English theme overrides the other language theme and vice versa.

So how can I support multiple language styling with SXA?

Comment: Blob field (`/sitecore/templates/System/Media/Unversioned/File/Media/Blob` ) is a shared field, how would you manage multiple versions? 
Are you talking about media items or content items (style items under `Presentation/Styles`)?

Comment: what i need to change is the css and style to be diff between the two language

Answer (score 1):

> what I need to change is the css and style to be diff between the two language

`Media` field is **shared** thus you cannot do it right now.(by default theme's media items are unversioned).

[image]

Have you tried to define different directions in common CSS and enable it depending on a lang attribute in `html` tag?

[image]